# Failed to start wolkenkit

Tags: docker, wolkenkit

I try to run wolkenkit (v3.1.0) on Ubuntu 18.04 with nodejs v. node v10.13.0
 using the official [tutorial](https://docs.wolkenkit.io/3.1.0/getting-started/installing-wolkenkit/installing-on-linux/), but the framework complains when I try to start it within the sample chat application directory:

```
  $ wolkenkit start --verbose
  Starting the application...
  Failed to reach Docker server.
  Failed to start the application.
  Docker not reachable.
  DockerNotReachable: Docker not reachable.
    at Object._callee$ (~/.nvm/versions/node/v10.13.0/lib/node_modules/wolkenkit/dist/docker/ping.js:98:19)
    at tryCatch (~/.nvm/versions/node/v10.13.0/lib/node_modules/wolkenkit/node_modules/@babel/runtime/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:62:40)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (~/.nvm/versions/node/v10.13.0/lib/node_modules/wolkenkit/node_modules/@babel/runtime/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:288:22)
    at Generator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as throw] (~/.nvm/versions/node/v10.13.0/lib/node_modules/wolkenkit/node_modules/@babel/runtime/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:114:21)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (~/.nvm/versions/node/v10.13.0/lib/node_modules/wolkenkit/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:3:24)
    at _throw (~/.nvm/versions/node/v10.13.0/lib/node_modules/wolkenkit/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:29:9)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

Docker is set up up and running:

```
$ sudo service docker status
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2019-07-09 18:47:51 CEST; 9min ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
 Main PID: 11342 (dockerd)
    Tasks: 22
   CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
           └─11342 /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock
```

and with the required version:

```
$ docker --version
Docker version 18.09.7, build 2d0083d
```

Is there anything I'm forgetting here?

Comment: Please provide some logs, won't be able to help.

Comment: @mchawre Basically, the logs already tell what the problem is: The wolkenkit CLI can't reach the Docker server. @harnen Could you please try to rerun `wolkenkit start`, but this time with the `--verbose` flag, and add the additional output to the question?

Comment: @GoloRoden Thanks. I've updated the post with --verbose. Didn't see this option in wolkenkit help.

Comment: Don't worry :-). This error happens if the wolkenkit CLI is not able to parse the output of `docker version --format "{{json .}}` (which tbh never happened to me before). Could you please run this command and also provide its output? PS: Maybe the wolkenkit Slack at http://slackin.wolkenkit.io/ is a better place to discuss this and figure out what the problem is. We could then still post the final answer here, to help others, too. PPS: Or you might want to open an issue on GitHub, at https://github.com/thenativeweb/wolkenkit/issues/new?template=bug.md

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the comments, I've figured out that `docker version --format "{{json .}}` required by wolkenkit doesn't run correctly without root privileges.

Invoking wolkenkit with `sudo wolkenkit start` solved the issue.

Comment: Maybe instead of running wolkenkit with sudo it may also be an option to allow non-root users to use the Docker CLI.

Comment: Yes adding non-root user to docker group should help here. https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/linux-postinstall/#manage-docker-as-a-non-root-user

Comment: Be advised that allowing non-`root` users access to your Docker daemon effectively circumvents the operating system's security system and allows these users to act as root anyway. So it might be better to explicitly use `sudo` not to fool anyone about this fact. This is a systemic problem about Docker which alternatives like Podman solve.